# How to combine namespaces from separate XML schemas (russian doll configuration)?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I need to de-normalize an XML schema to generate documentation for some people that will create documents that conform to the schema. The users have no knowledge of XSD and will most likely never learn. The tools I've seen are able to generate documentation for fellow XSD developers, but my users are not interested in the details of how the schema is constructed, they only want to know what they can and must do to create valid documents.

So, I'm looking for a way to resolve all imported namespaces, includes and references in an XML schema and generate a denormalized version that I can use to (in turn) generate user documentation.

**Question**:
I am able to resolve most includes and references. What I need is to know is how can I resolve all imported/included namespaces to fit into one single XSD?

The following are the 4 schemas that are linked to each other and I'm looking to move everything to the "main_schema.xsd" as that is the one currently being referred to by the people. (Note: removing namespaces is not an option - data in XML files that the XSDs are validated against have namespaces).

*Sample data file that is successfully being validated against "main_schema.xsd"*

```
<schema_actions xmlns="http://abcd.com/schema/v1" xmlns:id="http://abcd.com/schema/InstrumentMaster/v1" created="2018-01-03T14:21:00.601-05:00" source="abcd">
  <event>
    <instrument>
      <id:code scheme="123">LoremIpsum123</id:code>
      <id:code scheme="124">LoremIpsum124</id:code>
      <id:code scheme="125">LoremIpsum125</id:code>
      <id:code scheme="321">LoremIpsum321</id:code>
      <id:code scheme="320">LoremIpsum320</id:code>
    </instrument>
  </event>
</schema_actions>
```

*main_schema.xsd*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="v1.0" targetNamespace="http://abcd.com/schema/v1">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="data_format_schema.xsd"/>
</xs:schema>
```

*data_format_schema.xsd*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:uca="http://abcd.com/schema/v1" xmlns:id="http://abcd.com/schema/InstrumentMaster/v1" xmlns:meta="http://abcd.com/schema/outgoing/v1" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="v1.0">
    <xs:import namespace="http://abcd.com/schema/outgoing/v1" schemaLocation="outgoing.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://abcd.com/schema/InstrumentMaster/v1" schemaLocation="master_information.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="schema_actions">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="event" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="meta:outgoing"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="event" type="Trigger_Action"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Trigger_Action">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="instrument" type="id:Instrument"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="meta:outgoing"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

*master_information.xsd*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb" xmlns:uca="http://abcd.com/schema/InstrumentMaster/v1" targetNamespace="http://abcd.com/schema/InstrumentMaster/v1" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="v1.0">
    <xs:complexType name="Code">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="scheme" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Instrument">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="code" type="uca:Code" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

*outgoing.xsd*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb" targetNamespace="http://abcd.com/schema/outgoing/v1" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="v1.0">
    <xs:attributeGroup name="outgoing">
        <xs:attribute name="source" fixed="abcd" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute name="created" type="xs:dateTime" use="optional"/>
        <xs:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:attributeGroup>
</xs:schema>
```

Any insight into this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to generate documentation for (or otherwise process) a set of schema documents, I typically put them all into a single XML document, as children of a wrapper element to which I give a name like `collection`.  (Well, actually, that's not true; I normally wrap each `xsd:schema` element in a parent element with information about the URI from which the schema document was retrieved, the date and time of retrieval, and anything else I think will help six or twenty months later when a question arises and I have to look at it again.)

As Michael Kay observes, this XML document is not an XSD schema document; it is an XML document which contains several XSD schema documents.  Not all XSD-aware software will do well with such a collection (although nothing in the XSD spec requires the `xsd:schema` element to be the outermost element of its XML document), but if you're writing the code to generate the documentation, that needn't worry you.

Answer (score 1):

XSD syntax requires that if two global declarations have a different target namespace, then the declarations appear in different schema documents. You can merge declarations into a single file any way you like, but that file will not be an XSD schema document.